# Join tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this problem

1. I have table with singers name
2. I have tables with each singer albums
3. I have tables with songs of album of every singer in the first table

My question is how to select example :

```
Rihanna -> Rihannas' album -> songs in the album
```

Comment: How are these tables related to each other?  Have you identified Primary and Foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you want to achieve.

But you can select every album of a specific singer with:

```
SELECT .. FROM album WHERE singer_id = ?
```

And you can select every song of an album with this:

```
SELECT .. FROM song WHERE album_id = ?
```

If you want to select every song of a singer you can do it like this

```
SELECT .. FROM song, album WHERE song.album_id = album.id AND album.singer_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You join the tables
You will have to give an example of the table layout for a good example but it goes something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  (tblSingers S INNER JOIN  tblAlbums A ON S.singer_id=A.singer_id)
      INNER JOIN tblSongs G ON G.album_id=A.album_id
```